# Side Light issues (Daytime running lights) - 51 plate Clio

Tags: electrical, lights, clio

It's MOT time for the MillerMobile soon. I've managed to fix a few issues but this one has me stumped.

The drivers side side light (aka Daytime running light) is not working and its the only one on that headlight cluster that doesn't. I've checked the bulb and the filament looks intact, but I've swapped it with another that should work and it's still dead.

From my understanding of the layout of the fuses, there's just one that covers all the headlights at the front, so by virtue of the fact that the other lights all work OK, that won't be the problem.

I've done a bit of searching on the internet to no avail, so can anyone give me a list of things to check? I'm thinking a good place to start is probably a multimeter and the light connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer -

Turns out there are two bulbs to check in that part of the front light cluster! Didn't realise this and sure enough, the other bulb was the one for the running lights and was blown.